# Magento 2.3.2. Why is my VAT Tax Rate Changing without me changing it?

Tags: magento2, tax, magento2.3.2, vat

Bizarre problem here. I live in the UK so have VAT rates set at 20%.
All vatable products are assigned 'M2E Product Tax Class' which has been assigned the tax rate of 20%. All has been hunky dory for 4 years, then at about 1am on 10th July, this VAT rate changed to 4.97%. I changed it back, only for it to change again a day later to 5.01%. I then assigned a new 20% rate to the tax rule which seemed OK for a few days, but have just noticed that it has again changed to 4.97%!!! Does anyone know what could be causing this. I don't think anyone is deliberately changing it within the company.

TIA

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: i have the same problem

Comment: I have solved the problem but I'm not sure how. I removed a couple of extensions and changed the name of my default tax rate to the same name as the tax rate given in M2E Pro (The ebay and Amazon channel extension). I think the issue was in the latter. Sorry, I can't be more help. Maybe look at removing your new extensions one by one until you can pinpoint the issue.

Comment: its, okay, i created a custom module to override the rates from configuration